# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/compiler/IC$Result

Tags: scala, sbt, ebean, intellij-14

Hope someone can help me to get rid of this issue.

When I add **addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")** to plugins.sbt then I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/compiler/IC$Result

**plugins.sbt:**

```
logLevel := Level.Warn

resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.4.3")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0")
```

**build.sbt:**

```
name := "HelloWorld"

version := "1.0"

lazy val `helloworld` = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq( jdbc , cache , ws, "org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.9.Final" )

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+=  baseDirectory ( _ /"target/web/public/test" )
```

**I get the fallowing exception:**

> Error:Error while importing SBT project: ...  at
>   sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:71)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$$anonfun$runWithNewLog$1.apply(MainLoop.scala:66)    at
>   sbt.Using.apply(Using.scala:25)   at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runWithNewLog(MainLoop.scala:66)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runAndClearLast(MainLoop.scala:49)  at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runLoggedLoop(MainLoop.scala:33)    at
>   sbt.MainLoop$.runLogged(MainLoop.scala:25)    at
>   sbt.StandardMain$.runManaged(Main.scala:57)   at
>   sbt.xMain.run(Main.scala:29)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Launch.scala:109)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.withContextLoader(Launch.scala:129)     at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.run(Launch.scala:109)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Launch.scala:36)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.launch(Launch.scala:117)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:19)  at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:44)    at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)   at
>   xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala) [error]
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sbt/compiler/IC$Result [error] Use
>   'last' for the full log.
>
> See complete log in
>   C:\Users\Username.IntelliJIdea14\system\log\sbt.last.log

Can anyone help?

Comment: If the error occur only when `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-play-ebean" % "1.0.0") ` is added I can only speculate that this plugin was compiled with the wrong scala version.

Answer (score 2):

**Solution:**
I had to update the **SBT Version to 0.13.9**. That solved the above mentioned problem.